# Недопонимание с FD_ISSET() для функции select()

Tags: c

После вызова функции `select()`, которая выглядит так:

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
                  fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

мы можем вызвать макрос `FD_ISSET()` для дескриптора для проверки флага (готов ли наш дескриптор)

```
void FD_ISSET(int fd, fd_set *set);
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, после вызова макроса `FD_ISSET()` для дескриптора, у которого поднят флаг, опускается ли этот флаг после вызова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В мане написано следующее:

```
Four macros are provided to manipulate the sets.

  FD_ZERO() clears a set.
  FD_SET() and FD_CLR()  respectively  add  and remove a given file descriptor from a set.
  FD_ISSET() tests to see if a file descriptor is part of the set;
```

Я понимаю это вполне однозначно: сбрасывает бит макрос FD_CLR(), а FD_ISSET() только проверяет этот бит.

Answer (score 1):

Почему используете именно select()? Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону poll()
[здесь](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).
А по вашему вопросу посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/376364/).